# How to use TfidfVectorizer on dataframe

Tags: python, text-classification

I have the dataframe which has 3 colums(Positive Reviews, Negative and Score):

```
 negative                                        Positive               Label  
0 [there, were, issues, with, the, wifi, c]     [no, positive]             1  
1 [rooms, could, do, with, a, bit, of, a]   [the, well, meaning, staff]   2.5
```

I want to apply the `TfidfVectorizer` on the dataframe. I have written the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer  
df_x=train_df["Positive"]  
df_y=train_df["Score"]  
cv = TfidfVectorizer()   
df_xcv = cv.fit_transform(df_x)  
a=df_xcv.toarray()  
cv.get_feature_names()
```

which is giving an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: Your question is badly formated. I suppose the content of the dataframe which should be string is a list. Try convert the list content to string ''.join(list)

Answer (score 1):

The error arises from the fact that `TfidfVectorizer()` instance has not been fitted and yet, you are trying to access the `get_feature_names` method

Try this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  
df_x=train_df["Positive"]  
df_y=train_df["Score"]  
cv = TfidfVectorizer().fit(df_x)  
df_xcv = cv.transform(df_x)  
a=df_xcv.toarray()  
cv.get_feature_names()
```